# Testing object with "if defined?"

Tags: ruby

I am trying to create a method to determine if an object (in a array) exists, and if it is Numeric.

My current code is:

```
foo = [123, 456, 789, 012]

if defined?(foo[0]) and foo[0].is_a? Numeric
    foo_at_zero = foo[0]
else
    foo_at_zero = "N/A"
    puts "Cannot find data for foo at place zero"
end

puts foo_at_zero
```

However, my results are not what I expect. When I change the `if defined?` to an element in the array I have not defined, it still returns as true:

```
foo = [123, 456, 789, 012]

if defined?(foo[100]) and foo[0].is_a? Numeric
    foo_at_zero = foo[0]
else
    foo_at_zero = "N/A"
    puts "Cannot find data for foo at place zero"
end

puts foo_at_zero
```

returns the value at `foo[0].`

It appears `if defined?` does not appropriately test whether or not an object exists. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: Check the value for nil.

Comment: Check your condition: `defined? foo[100] # => "method"`

Comment: `if foo[100] and foo[0].is_a? Numeric` is not a robust statement, as it doesn't work when `foo.size > 100` and `foo[100] => nil`. You might argue that no element of `foo` would have been set to `nil` here, but wouldn't it be better to write `if (i<foo.size) and f[i].is_a? Numeric`, which is really what you mean? This works even if `foo[100] => nil`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check what `defined?(foo[100])` is returning, it is not actually `false`, it's returning that the expression it is evaluating (`foo[100]`) is a method (which is defined) of the class Array:

```
puts defined?(foo[100]) => method
```

For the purposes of your exercise I believe this could work for you:

```
foo = [123, 456, 789, 012]

if (foo[100] != nil) and (foo[0].is_a? Numeric)
    foo_at_zero = foo[0]
else
    foo_at_zero = "N/A"
    puts "Cannot find data for foo at place zero"
end

puts foo_at_zero
```

Check `if foo[100] != nil` and you will know if the element in there is defined or not.

**UPDATE:**
I would do something like this:

```
foo = [123, 456, 789, 012]

def validate value
    foo_at_zero = "N/A"
    if (value != nil) and (value.is_a? Numeric)
        foo_at_zero = value
    end
    return foo_at_zero
end

puts validate foo[0]
```

Comment: Ok that makes a lot of sense why no matter what the value, it would always be true. What would be the best way of making this verification? Say if i wanted to call a method where foo_at_zero would check these conditions before assigning to the value?

Comment: Not sure if I understood you correctly, correct me if I'm wrong, you want to put this code inside a method that makes these validations and returns the appropriate value of foo_at_zero?

Comment: Yes. Im having a hard time making a method where before is assigns the variable, it checks != nil and ia a? Numeric. Otherwise, the assignment is "N/A"

Comment: What if `foo = Array.new(101) { 0 }; foo[100] = nil`?